# Unable to display actual material-ui icon within my nav menu

Tags: javascript, arrays, material-ui, icons, html-escape-characters

Using Material-UI icons like `<AddOutlinedIcon />` as shown below, how can I actually make the icon appear in my nav menu as atm it displays the tags/word `<AddOutlinedIcon />` before my menu name?

Unsure if I need to escape this inorder to display actual icon?

It should actually be displaying a `+` icon before my menu name.

```
  const menuList = [];

  myMenu.map(menuListItem =>
    menuList.push({
      id: menuListItem.manu_name,
      icon: '<AddOutlinedIcon />',          
      active: false
    })
  )
```

Comment: nit: You can change `map` to `forEach`.

Comment: How are you using the `menuList`? Please post a minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing the AddOutlinedIcon as a string value?

```
  const menuList = [];

  myMenu.map(menuListItem =>
    menuList.push({
      id: menuListItem.manu_name,
      icon: <AddOutlinedIcon />,          
      active: false
    })
  )
```